# Installing a 3TB storage hdd with dual boot Windows 7x64 and Ubuntu 12.04ltsX64

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I am in the middle of a build and ran into a problem with the GPT format of a 3TB hdd.

The build is:

- ASUS a55bm-e motherboard.
- AMD A10 processor black 7850 (I think).
- Seagate 1TB with Ubuntu and Windows installed (MBR/Legacy).
- AMD Radeon RAM 8GB single stick 1600 MHz
- Installing a Toshiba 3TB HDD in GPT format

Both OS's are installed and functioning beautifully

The 3TB was enabled as dynamic with disk management tool and is usable in Windows

I cannot access it unless I run `gparted` or similar tools while in Ubuntu (as in it does not show up in the Unity desktop anywhere)

The problem is that I do not want to format the drive for Ubuntu for fear of losing access to it in Windows. I researched the error and it was a sector alignment issue with Ubuntu. From what I understand is that it is a simple fix just to realign the sectors to match Ubuntu but will that unalign the sectors with windows?

I am building this for a friend and he needs access to it in both operating systems.

Is there a way to reconcile the issue here and align the drive with both OS's? Neither drive is an SSD The main problem is the size of the drive and the required format that has to come with that.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you converted it to dynamic, that is Windows proprietary and will not work with Linux. With gpt it may be seen as LDM.

You need to undo the dynamic and just have NTFS partitions which will work with Windows and Linux. And with new 4K drives partitions need to be aligned or else you will have issues. But all the newer partition tools will create standard partitions with alignment.

Windows nor Linux does not have tools to undo the dynamic but some third party Windows partitioning tools may undo it without having to totally erase drive.

Best to check on a Windows forum for details.

Anyone with a large drive can use gparted or gdisk (in repository) to correctly create partitions with alignment.

Alignment 2048 sectors Advanced Format drives

[Proper alignment of partitions on an Advanced Format HDD using Parted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201164/proper-alignment-of-partitions-on-an-advanced-format-hdd-using-parted)

Comment: Thank you so much! I do not  mind a total wipe at this point to reset the Dynamic setting. One further question for you is the 2048 alignment works with both windows and Ubuntu?

Comment: I don't know how else to contact you except this :). Thank you for your help and don't bother to reply to my last question. I understand what you meant by that now and I followed your link to the answer as well! Again thank you! You rock!